# Mt. Gox had 5 billion bitcoins?

Tags: mtgox

In the statement of liabilities issued by Mt. Gox after its bankruptcy it shows the following figures as totals:

[image]

The statement amount of "Deposited BTC" is 5,202,383,086.88638 bitcoins, which is over 5 billion bitcoins. Since at the time of Mt. Gox's bankruptcy in 2013, there were only about 10 million bitcoins in existence, the statement would seem to be impossible.

Is there something I don't understand about the Japanese number system?

Comment: AFAIK Japan uses the same number system as everybody else.  It looks to me like it is the total amount of the claims filed against them, by people claiming to have been depositors.  If so, then evidently a lot of these claims are inaccurate or fake or duplicates.  But I don't see this as saying that MtGox ever had 5 billion bitcoins.

Comment: Can you add a link to the full document where these numbers came from?  The context might be helpful in understanding what they mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like some of the claims were spurious and had grossly exaggerated values. The accepted claims by the bankruptcy trustee were:

45,609,593,503 JPY

which is more reasonable.